# How to use openshift source-to-image library instead of s2i binary or executable file

Tags: docker, go, github, openshift, s2i

How to use openshift source-to-image library https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image using go language,instead of s2i executable to build a new image from existing builder images from docker hub.

I need to create a new image by using above library and not using s2i.exe.

I have tried using https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image/blob/master/pkg/build/strategies/dockerfile/dockerfile.go Build function but it gives me an error.

Can anyone tell me or atleast guide me how to use this library to create a new image from existing docker hub builder images, by not using s2i executable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give some background on why you are trying to do this? In being able to understand that, may be able to suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: Yeah sure.... 
Currently i am using s2i executable from golang exec.Command function to build a new image from existing builder image (because I was unable to find any methods defined by openshift/source-to-image) which I think, is not a good a way to use it.
So I am thinking of new approaches to use it and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I can infer that much. Was more interested in the bigger picture of how S2I fits into the overall custom build system you seem to have.

Comment: Yes, actually I figured out how to use source-to-image library but still my goal is to capture the logs and to show them on web page dynamically, but I am unable to do that.